# Missing .NET Core SDK / Setting up System Environment for C# on MacOS Monterey / Can't run C# in VSCode

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-code, system, vscode-extensions

I got a "failed to run test because undefined" error when running "Hello World" code and my C# VSCode extension tells me the .Net Core SDK is missing, which I'm assuming is two related problems. so I installed the .Net Core SDK. However, this did not fix the errors.

Reading through stackoverflow threads, I found that I was missing the .zprofile and System Environment files in my user profile. I have no idea how to set up a system environment or what that entails. I was just trying to run Hello World, and now I'm trying not to do any permanent damage in my terminal or systems folders.

Is there a way to copy and paste what I need for VSCode to start working with C#, or a step by step guide to create the System Environment files, or just a quick way to make VSCode start working?

All I have is a .bash_history file and a .bash_sessions folder, and I don't think those even relate to zsh. I created a .zprofile but have no idea what to put in it because I have no idea where the dotnet.exe is (my .local/share folder is empty and searches for the dotnet come up with nothing).
I'm sorry if this is redundant or too basic, I really read for hours on here trying to troubleshoot without bothering anybody. I'm at wits end and too new to this to confidently navigate fixing it.

I tried installing the .Net Core SDK. I tried to creating the .zprofile inside of my user folder. I tried populating the .zprofile with `ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet /usr/local/bin/` as specified on other StackOverflow thread, and I tried to find the dotnet.exe that I installed. I have tried using the terminal to find the dotnet file with `find / -name dotnet`, it did not find anything, I also tried `dotnet --list-sdks` and it did not find anything. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling VSCode and C# the extension on seperate occassions and I got the same result. I've tried installing Mono as suggested in a different stackoverflow thread, nothing changed as far as my issue goes. I've tried running the dotnet command on the terminal as specified in the .Net Core SDK setup, and it has not worked. I also tried restarting VSCode and my computer as a whole throughout this process, and nothing has changed with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of testing while setting up a new MacBook Pro M2 for C# this spring, and found that I had to use a specific SDK version.

I automated the setup and installation of my Mac, so you can have a look at what I did on line `397` to `413` here: https://github.com/lewiuberg/setup/blob/main/automated-setup/terminal.sh#L397

I hope this works for you too!